# how to add some own forms in a ASP.NET MVC create view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a problem, i had created a controller and a view for adding a new item from a specific model. the view looks like:

```
@modelModels.UserItem

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
}

<h2>New</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)  
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Device</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(UserItem useritem)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.UserItems.AddObject(useritem);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(useritems);
}
```

how i want to add a dropdown to the form in the view like this:

```
<select id="Select1">
    <option>MARS</option>
</select>
```

how to access the data from the form after it was submitted in the controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have view model for your page,this view model will be used in your view. So, only include fields from your model that you really need. In Get action you should create this view model and get the needed properties from your model and map them to your view model.

```
public class UserItemViewModel
{
    /* Properties you want from your model */
    public string Property1                           { get; set; }
    public string Property2                           { get; set; }
    public string Property3                           { get; set; }

    /* Property to keep selected item */
    public string SelectedItem                        { get; set; }
    /* Set of items to fill dropdown */
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectOptions  { get; set; }

    /* Fill the SelectListHere. This will be called from index controller */
    public void FillOptions()
    {
        var items = new[] { "Mars", "Venus" }.
              Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x, Text = x });

        SelectOptions= new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```

Change controller for receiving ViewModel instead of Model itself.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New(UserItemViewModel useritem)
{
    /* Repopulate the dropdown, since the values are not posted with model. */
    userItem.FillOptions();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /* Create your actual model and add it to db */

        // TODO: Map your properties from model to view model.
        // Let's say you created a model with name userItemModel
        db.UserItems.AddObject(userItemModel);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(useritem);
}
```

You might need to change Index view controller little.(to fill dropdown)

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    /* Create new viewmodel fill the dropdown and pass it to view */
    var viewModel = new UserItemViewModel();
    viewModel.FillOptitons();

    //TODO : From your model fill the required properties in view model as I mention.

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And your view,

```
/* Strongly typed view with viewmodel instead of model itself */
@modelModels.UserItemViewModel

/* This is the dropdown */
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.SelectOptions)
```

Comment: is there no way without changing the model?

Comment: @gurehbgui, there is but I won't show it because it is not the correct thing to do. `emre nevayeshirazi` provided you with the correct answer (+1 for him): **use view models** and stop passing your domain entities to the views.

Comment: No, I won't show it because I don't consider this a good practice and I don't wanna see bad practices shown on Stack Overflow. Remember that this is a well referenced site where many people might stumble upon and I really don't want them making the same mistake as you.

Comment: @gurehbgui you are not changing the model actually. you are using another level of abstraction. your model stays same, you just use it inside of viewmodel instead of passing it to view directly.

Comment: i have a error in the view with the @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.SelectOptions)
i'm getting a nullReferenceException

Comment: try to call  userItem.FillOptitons(); again in New action. You might need to re populate the dropdown if the validation fails in New action. But I have given this example from my own code and it works.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi but now i have a other problem, after sumbmitting, the useritem is always null and has no useritem.UserItem

Comment: have you changed your html helpers from @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name) to @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserItem.name) ?

Comment: i dont know what i did but now it is working, but it is the same code. thynk you very much

Answer (score 0):

1. Add that property to your model
2. Use builtin `EditorFor`(preffered) or hand-written html to generate client-side input for that property.
3. Access submitted value by inspecting that property when user submits the form

Comment: is there no way without changing the model?

Answer (score 0):

I like emre's proposition of having a viewModel and I think is the Best solution to your question however just in case you don't want to go that way (you must have a really good reason because it is best) and still want a way to access the values of a form directly you can always use:
        var x = Request["myFiledName"];
inside your controller to get to the values passed by your form.